# Suggestion needed for indexing huge table

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I need to build an history report which provide READ access only from a table with 150GB size. I would like to know should i create the column indexes for all the below:

1. My report has 10 filters asking for user input.E.g. Datetime, Varchar. Should i create 10 indexes for all of them?
2. My report has 10 default hard coded filter e.g. `where code="RAM"`. Should i create another 10 indexes for all of them?

My main concern is the performance issue.

Comment: How many rows remain after applying the 10 default hard coded filters? A daily ofload or even an indexed view might be a good starting point.

Comment: I'm also assuming you can't create a summary/reporting table

Comment: 150gb is - ah - not hugh. guy ;) It is mid size if thigns are good,but not big. Grab some SSD and see the thing flying (just upgrading our server to handle 3000gb data).

Comment: What version of database system you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you say your primary concern is performance. Performance reading or performance writing?

Because in theory you could index a table to death which would make reads great, but they would need to be maintained and updated every time you inserted or updated a row.

Second select indicies should be based on which queries are frequently run against your table.

For example, imagine you have a table with columns `ID, Type, TextValue`. In your application you have a `GetByID()` method and a `ListWithType()` method. Your indicies should be based on what SQL is trying to filter/join by. In this case ID (your PK obviously) and a non-unique index on Type.

- Decide which performance is important (read or write)
- Watch your code and observe the common and slow queries
- Create indicies based on the various filters/joins you're doing.

This is obviously a simplistic overview. I suggest you read up on how to read a [SQL Execution Plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan) and change your indicies to improve it.

Finally, when you create indicies make sure you select an appropriate [fill factor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177459.aspx) (this is based on how the table is used) or you'll be constantly rebuilding them.

Comment: @belinq I assumed so, that's the most common problem and tailored most of my answer towards it.